# Is there anyway to use array like below in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

```
int a[][] = new int[1][2];
a[0][0] = 1;
```

my requirement is allocate a multidimensional array on heap, and using it like array not pointer, but while I try this , it doesn't work. I wish there is an easy way which like java:`int[][] a = new int[1][2]`.

Thanks for your help.....

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: "using it like array not pointer". Wait, what? `int ** ptr = magicFunc(1,2); ptr[0][0] = 0;`

Comment: @Jarod42: "my requirement …". Probably a homework question, so `std::vector` or `std::array` are probably prohibited.

Comment: I'm sorry for  my bad english..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way is like that:

```
int **arr = new int *arr[SIZE_X];
arr[0] = new int[SIZE_X * SIZE_Y];
for (int i = 1; i < SIZE_X; i++)
    arr[i] = arr[0] + i*SIZE_Y;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Don't forget the `delete[]`.

Comment: thank you, and i want these memories are continuous. How should I do

Comment: This memory actually is continuous. By `new int[SIZE_X * SIZE_Y];` you declare `SIZE_X * SIZE_Y` units of int size of continues memory each column of the array gets however only the SIZE_Y of this memory "for its purpose".

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with

```
int (*arr)[M] = new int[N][M];
// M must be constant expressions that evaluate to positive value
```

in C++11, `auto` can be used

```
auto arr = new int[N][M];
// M must be constant expressions that evaluate to positive value
```

the memory should be deallocated

```
auto arr = new int[1][2];
arr[0][0] = 1;
delete[] arr;
```

Last but not least, unless you have good reason, use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead.